# ID check char Method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm stuck in my code I have everything initialize I need to find 
An employee’s ID is of the length of 8 or more characters and is composed of only capital letters
and digits. The first two characters must be capital letters and the ID must contain at least 2 digits. Write
a method that takes an employee’s ID as an array of characters and returns true if the ID is valid and false
otherwise.
I have my code but it won't increment once it finds the first two indexes if they are Capital letters

```
public static boolean isValidID(char [] id) {      

      if(id.length >= 8)
      {
        validLen = true;
      }
      else if(id.length < 8)
      {
         validLen = false;
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
      {  
            if(Character.isUpperCase(0))
            {
               check2Cap++;
            }
            else if(Character.isUpperCase(1))
            {
               check2Cap++;   
            }
            else if(Character.isDigit(i))
            {
               check2Digits++;
            }          

     }  
     if(check2Cap == 2)
     {
        checkCapital = true;
     }
     if(check2Digits >= 2)
     {
        checkDig = true;
     } 
     return validLen && checkCapital && checkDig;
}
```

Comment: I am assuming you are just beginning learning Java, but keep in your mind if you can that regular expressions (REs) are the best way to test strings like this.

Comment: When you're doing your upper-case comparisons, it should be something like Character.isUpperCase(id[0]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the upper case check outside the loop.

Character.isDigit(i) - > Wrong check. You should check against the characters and not the index.

---

Something like this shall work

```
  public static boolean isValidID(char [] id) {      

  boolean validStruct = (id.length >= 8) && (Character.isUpperCase(id[0]) && (Character.isUpperCase(id[1]))) ; 
  int numDigits =0 ;

  for(int i = 0; validStruct && i < id.length ; i++)
  {  
     if(Character.isDigit(id[i]))
         numDigits+=1; 
  }  
 return validStruct && (numDigits >= 2);
```

}

---

```
 public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
     System.out.println(isValidID("FRUMT3UMPO".toCharArray()));
     System.out.println(isValidID("GE7IMTWIK5".toCharArray()));
    }
```

Output -

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Uses code points which is nice. It is a bit wasteful with 2 Stream representations of the characters as code point values but its elegant which is nice. Definitely not the most performant piece of code.

```java
    private static boolean valid(char[] id, int minimumLength, int minimumDigits, int minimumUppercase, int firstNLetter) {
        if (id.length < minimumLength) {
            return false;
        }
        String idAsString = new String(id);

        if (!idAsString.codePoints().limit(firstNLetter).allMatch(Character::isLetter)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (idAsString.codePoints().filter(Character::isDigit).count() < minimumDigits) {
            return false;
        }

        return idAsString.codePoints().filter(Character::isUpperCase).count() >= minimumUppercase;
    }
```

```java
boolean first = valid("GE7IMTWIK5".toCharArray(), 8, 2, 2, 2);

boolean second = valid("FRUMT3UMPO".toCharArray(), 8, 2, 2, 2);

System.out.println(String.format("first=%s, second=%s", first, second));
```

```
first=true, second=false
```

Comment: What about the requirement that the first two characters be letters?

Comment: Oh! my bad, one moment! Edit; Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

First, your Character.XXX() calls should use `id[i]`, not `i` itself

Second, You should check for your initial capital letters first

```
  if (id[0] < 'A' || id[0] > 'Z') return false;
  if (id[1] < 'A' || id[1] > 'Z') return false;
  for(int i = 2; i < id.length; i++)
  {
        //The code below is now unnecessary
        if(Character.isUpperCase(0))
        {
           check2Cap++;
        }
        else if(Character.isUpperCase(1))
        {
           check2Cap++;   
        }
        //end unnecessary
        else if(Character.isDigit(id[i]))
        {
           check2Digits++;
        }          

 }
```